# Image analysis libraries/features

Tags: android, image-processing, android-camera, face-recognition

I have an idea to create an application which enable me to analyse an image from camera phone on android. I'm thinking about creating an application which will recognize faces (for now it's just an idea), but first I want to create something easier (like application which detects for example red square next to the blue circle). Has android any libraries or features which will help me to recognize shapes (like square, rectangle, circle) and colors in the picture which I made using my camera phone? Any suggestion welcome

Answer (score 5):

I think Augmented Reality in android will help you 
http://code.google.com/p/andar/

Comment: AndAR will allow the OP to detect circles etc. but atm does not have general face detection in it. If you create a marker with someone's face it might work, but I'm not sure. And even then, it'll only work for that exact face.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at http://opencv.org/android.

Face detector is already implemented by android api: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html